# Use streaming parser to extract images from PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using Apache PDFBox to extract images from large PDF files. (Using PDFBox is not a hard requirement. Aspose.PDF or another API is fine too.)

Currently, I'm parsing the file into a PDDocument, and then iterating over pages looking for images:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> imageDataList = new ArrayList<>();

try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath))) {
    PDPageTree list = document.getPages();
    for (PDPage page : list) {
        PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
        for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {
            PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);
            if (o instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                PDImageXObject pdImage = (PDImageXObject) o;
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream());
                BufferedImage image = pdImage.getImage();
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
                imageDataList.add(baos.toByteArray());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works, but uses a lot of memory. Is there a way to extract images without parsing the whole document into memory? I see that there's a streaming parser `PDFStreamParser`, but I don't understand PDF internals and don't know what to do with the objects returned by `PDFStreamParser.parseNextToken()`.

Comment: Unfortunately pdf as a whole is not a file format that naturally gives rise to a streaming access. Nonetheless one can restrict pdf parsing to the actually required parts of the pdf for the tak at hand. Such parsing-on-demand will become part of pdfbox soon. Btw, what you're using is plain pdfbox, no need for poi here.

Comment: @mkl Thank you, and you're right, I meant pdfbox. I wasn't careful with my wording, fixed.

Comment: PDFStreamParser is just for the (page / form / pattern) content streams. The parse on demand that mkl mentioned is being tested in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4549 svn: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/branches/issue4569